# Recurrence of binary search(time of inserting element into array)

Tags: arrays, sorting

> We can express insertion sort as a recursive procedure as follows. In
>   order to sort. In order to sort A[1..n], we recursively sort A[1..n−1]
>   and then insert A[n] into the sorted array A[1..n−1]. Write a
>   recurrence for the running time of this recursive version of insertion
>   sort.

It's clear that it takes T(n-1) times to sort the array (because we don't need to sort last element). But I don't understand why it takes O(n) to insert an element into a sorted array.

Suppose we have an array: `A = 41;52;26;38;57;9;49.` The worst case scenario, that we have to go through the whole array in order to insert last element n at the beginning of the array. But I thought,that it takes O(n-1) time, because we go through n-1 elements in the array.

Can you explain my mistake and the logic of the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like O(n-1).
Constants are ignore in Big O notation. So its O(n).
You need to clear your basics of analysis of algorithms.

You can refer here

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fundamentals-of-algorithms/#AnalysisofAlgorithms

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just one additional question: what is the difference between T(n), which we was used to define time of sorting array, and big O notation, which was used to define insertion time?

Comment: I understood the definitions but I can't understand why they can be used in one equation, like in my question?

Comment: It's because T(n-1) is fixed and O(n) can vary(worst and best case scenarios?)